# Verificar direcciones de correo de dominios como "Gmail.com" en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, formularios

me gustaría saber como podría hacer que solamente unos determinados dominios puedan registrarse en mi plataforma a modo de combatir el spam. He estado revisando algunos foros pero no he encontrado lo que busco, por ejemplo esta:

```
<?php

$pattern = '/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD';

$emailaddress = 'test@gmail.com';

if (preg_match($pattern, $emailaddress) === 1) {
    // emailaddress is valid
}
```

Comprueba únicamente que el input tenga el `@` y el `.` pero no el dominio, es decir, que en mi input perfectamente podrían ponerme: `hjkjf3nkkj3f@dhejkefn.com`, es por eso que me gustaría permitir por ejemplo los emails de `@gmail` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entendí lo que quieres hacer es comprobar el dominio del email para permitir únicamente dominios específicos como "gmail.com".

Si es ese el caso usaría `explode()`.

Ejemplo, supongamos que el usuario introduce el correo "juan@gmail.com"

```
$email = "juan@gmail.com"; //input

$separar = explode("@",$email);
```

Esto nos da el array `$separar` con los siguientes valores:

> $separar[0] -> "juan"
>
> $separar[1] -> "gmail.com"

Ahora para validar el dominio es tan sencillo como lo siguiente:

```
$allow = array("gmail.com","hotmail.com"); //dominios válidos
$dom = $separar[1];

if(in_array($dom,$allow)){
   //dominio válido
}else{
   //dominio inválido
}
```

También podrías validar dominio excluyendo el ".com" con otro `explode(".",$dom)`.

Espero que esto resuelva tu pregunta.

[explode() en PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, mañana aplicaré lo que me has dicho y te comentaré qué tal!

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y va de lujo!
Muchas gracias :D

Comment: @galaixagalicia Me alegro de que te haya funcionado. :)